# What can be used if I want to check if the element is present or not in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I just want to check if the element is present on the page or not?

I am confused with what can be used. What is feasible to use `isDisplayed()` or `isPresent()`?

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: use isdisplayed(); that would be better.

Comment: use webdriver.findElements(By.xpath("REQUIRED_XPATH")).size();  if its zero means element is not there on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no `isPresent` function
2. The `isDisplayed` returns `True` only if the element is displayed on the webpage and is actually visible.
3. If you just want to check if the element is present then you can do one of the following:

   - Put the code for `findElement` inside a try/catch block. If it goes inside `catch` with `NoSuchElementException` then the element is not present.
   - Do `findElements` instead of `findElement` and if length of the list returned by `findElements` is zero, then the element is not present.
   - In both the cases you need to make sure that you are finding the desired element using a unique selector.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify.. I've posted code below

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(final WebDriver driver, By by) {
        try {
            waitForElement(driver, by, 2);
            driver.findElement(by);

            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```